# RXJS steam with distinct and throttleTime

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I need help to create a RXJS stream which does the following.

Input: Keyboard inputevent a to z
Emit value if:

- Character has NOT been used before
- Character has been used before but it is more than 5 seconds ago.
  else discard value

Marble diagram (- is 1 second):

```
Input:  [aaa--b--b--aa--a-c-->
Output: [a----b-----a-----c-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group your input by character using [`groupBy`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/groupby). We can then grab the first occurrence in each group and finally merge everything back. As luck would have it, `groupBy` lets us define a duration selector to specify how long a group should live, so if we set that to 5 seconds, we basically "reset" each group after that time:

```
const source$ = fromEvent(document, 'keydown').pipe(
  map((evt: KeyboardEvent) => evt.key)
);

source$.pipe(
  // create one group per character, with each
  // group living for only up to 5 seconds
  groupBy(key => key, undefined, () => timer(5000)),

  // From each group, only take the first element
  map(group$ => group$.pipe(first())),

  // put everything back together
  mergeAll()
)
```